# Websocket en proyectos API .net core

Tags: api, .net-core, websocket

recientemente tengo un proyecto en el que tenemos que implementar una API de pedidos para call Center, en net core. Está API será consumida por una aplicación Android hecha en react native. Un requerimiento que se nos ha pedido es que la API esté corriendo un proceso para asignar pedidos a los repartidores y que cuando se le asigne un pedido a un repartidor determinado, este pueda recibir una notificación en su aplicación que le indique que posee una nueva orden. No sé si podrían iluminarme un poco por dónde tengo que ir, lo único que he investigado es sobre websocket, pero no sé realmente cómo hacer esa implementación.

Comment: necesitas hacer uso de SignalR que es la libreria que maneja los sockets en .net

Answer (score -1):

el json de la api deberia devolver un valor que indique que el registro fue registrado exitosamente, por ejemplo un 1o un true. Y con base en eso los desarrolladores de react navite hacen que se muestre la notificación. creo que la notificación debe hacerla mostrar el código de la app, no lo api. tu solo enviarias lo que mencioné mediante la api. no veo la necesidad de websokets

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. Por favor leer [answer]. Cuando tenga la reputación suficiente podrás dejar comentarios en cualquier publicación.